# Sending POST request through PHP using CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using CURL to send a JSON request to a URL.

This is my code:

```
$uri = "http://xxxxx:3434/config?command=xcxc";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);

$data = '{"Request":{"rel":{"sta":"0"}}}';

$headers= array('Authorization:Basic xxxxxx=','Content-Type: application/json'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); 

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The request isn't going through and returning HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate.The authorization key is correct, but is it the right way to pass the key (through array) ?

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: what does the result variable return??

Comment: You certainly get a result back. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work.

```
'Authorization:Basic xxxxxx='
```

was causing a problem and returning HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate (even though this was a correct Authorization key which I checked using a REST client and worked)

When I used a username/password combination instead, it worked.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```